# Vertical space before and after align environment

Tags: spacing, amsmath, align

I am wondering if it is possible in LaTeX to generally adjust the spacing before and after math in the `align` environment from `amsmath`.

From the [Mathmode-guide](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode) (by Herbert Voss) I gather that `\belowdisplayskip` and friends should do the job, but manipulating them doesn't yield any visible results.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It has a pretty clear effect to me:

```
\hrule
\begin{align}
f(x)&=x
\end{align}
\hrule
\vskip1cm
\belowdisplayskip=0pt
\hrule
\begin{align}
f(x)&=x
\end{align}
\hrule
```

Can you provide a minimal working example where it doesn't?

Comment: It seems that the difference between yours and mine was that I put \belowdisplayskip=0pt in the preamble rather than after \begin{document}. Indeed, putting it after the preamble yields results. This had never occured to me :-/ .. but thanks for the answer :-)

Comment: @plc -- in many document classes, `\belowdisplayskip` is reset every time the text size (e.g., `\small`, etc.) is reset.  although the reset is local, `\normalsize` is invoked as part of `\begin{document}`, overruling the setting you put in the preamble.