# Space Above Equations

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vertical spacing before and after equation environment: empty line or not?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77849/vertical-spacing-before-and-after-equation-environment-empty-line-or-not)

I am using iPython Notebooks and a utility called nbconvert to translate notebooks into LaTeX. One problem is generated equations have too much space on top; I tried to play with \baselineskip parameter without much success. Any ideas on how to fix this? I am attaching the generated code; I am looking for additive fixes, parameter settings using the packages present in the tex file - I do not have much control on the main part of the nbconvert tool, I prefer improving the existing usage scenario.

```
%% This file was auto-generated by IPython.
%% Conversion from the original notebook file:
%% test.ipynb
%%
\documentclass[11pt,english,fleqn]{article}

%% This is the automatic preamble used by IPython.  Note that it does *not*
%% include a documentclass declaration, that is added at runtime to the overall
%% document.

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

% needed for markdown enumerations to work
\usepackage{enumerate}

% Slightly bigger margins than the latex defaults
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}

% Define a few colors for use in code, links and cell shading
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{orange}{cmyk}{0,0.4,0.8,0.2}
\definecolor{darkorange}{rgb}{.71,0.21,0.01}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{.12,.54,.11}
\definecolor{myteal}{rgb}{.26, .44, .56}
\definecolor{gray}{gray}{0.45}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{.95}
\definecolor{mediumgray}{gray}{.8}
\definecolor{inputbackground}{rgb}{.95, .95, .85}
\definecolor{outputbackground}{rgb}{.95, .95, .95}
\definecolor{traceback}{rgb}{1, .95, .95}

% Framed environments for code cells (inputs, outputs, errors, ...).  The
% various uses of \unskip (or not) at the end were fine-tuned by hand, so don't
% randomly change them unless you're sure of the effect it will have.
\usepackage{framed}

% remove extraneous vertical space in boxes
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}

% codecell is the whole input+output set of blocks that a Code cell can
% generate.

% TODO: unfortunately, it seems that using a framed codecell environment breaks
% the ability of the frames inside of it to be broken across pages.  This
% causes at least the problem of having lots of empty space at the bottom of
% pages as new frames are moved to the next page, and if a single frame is too
% long to fit on a page, will completely stop latex from compiling the
% document.  So unless we figure out a solution to this, we'll have to instead
% leave the codecell env. as empty.  I'm keeping the original codecell
% definition here (a thin vertical bar) for reference, in case we find a
% solution to the page break issue.

%% \newenvironment{codecell}{%
%%     \def\FrameCommand{\color{mediumgray} \vrule width 1pt \hspace{5pt}}%
%%    \MakeFramed{\vspace{-0.5em}}}
%%  {\unskip\endMakeFramed}

% For now, make this a no-op...
\newenvironment{codecell}{}

 \newenvironment{codeinput}{%
   \def\FrameCommand{\colorbox{inputbackground}}%
   \MakeFramed{\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}
 {\unskip\endMakeFramed}

\newenvironment{codeoutput}{%
   \def\FrameCommand{\colorbox{outputbackground}}%
   \vspace{-1.4em}
   \MakeFramed{\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}
 {\unskip\medskip\endMakeFramed}

\newenvironment{traceback}{%
   \def\FrameCommand{\colorbox{traceback}}%
   \MakeFramed{\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}
 {\endMakeFramed}

% Use and configure listings package for nicely formatted code
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\lstset{
  language=python,
  inputencoding=utf8x,
  extendedchars=\true,
  aboveskip=\smallskipamount,
  belowskip=\smallskipamount,
  xleftmargin=2mm,
  breaklines=true,
  basicstyle=\small \ttfamily,
  showstringspaces=false,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries,
  commentstyle=\color{myteal},
  stringstyle=\color{darkgreen},
  identifierstyle=\color{darkorange},
  columns=fullflexible,  % tighter character kerning, like verb
}

% The hyperref package gives us a pdf with properly built
% internal navigation ('pdf bookmarks' for the table of contents,
% internal cross-reference links, web links for URLs, etc.)
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  breaklinks=true,  % so long urls are correctly broken across lines
  colorlinks=true,
  urlcolor=blue,
  linkcolor=darkorange,
  citecolor=darkgreen,
  }

% hardcode size of all verbatim environments to be a bit smaller
\makeatletter 
\g@addto@macro\@verbatim\small\topsep=0.5em\partopsep=0pt
\makeatother 

% Prevent overflowing lines due to urls and other hard-to-break entities.
\sloppy

\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{8pt}
\begin{document}

Some text

\[x^2 \]

Some more text

\[y^2 \]

Etc..

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Don't make paragraph breaks before and after equations, i.e. remove the empty lines around the equations.

Comment: Hi, the space comes from the authoring tool, before tex is generated, I dont have much control over that. If I remove emtpy lines around equations manually in tex file, yes output looks good. Is there any way to achieve that result without removing empty lines? Thanks.

Comment: You should modify that tool then. It's Open Source I guess, so you can read and modify it. Or suggest the improvement to the developers, since this is a bug. So I see not problem with closing the question, since it's a bug in a Python tool without direct relation to TeX, at least the consequence is a duplicate here.

Comment: OK.. I just modified the tool. Thanks for the comment.