# Inconsistent vertical space after first \begin{equation*}

Tags: spacing, equations

The `AlignBox` environment from [this TeX.sx answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31735/5699) can produce several consecutive `equation*` environments (when several pre-declared equation lines are inserted).

When the paragraph preceding the first `equation*` is more than one line long, the vertical spacing between the first and second equations is larger than for the others:

[image: On this screenshot, the spacing between AAAAAA and BBBBBB is 74px, whereas it is 53px between BBBBBB and CCCCCC.]

I'm curious about the reason this occurs (I noticed that when the line is very short, the equation is automatically moved up, to avoid an awkward large blank space).

Is there a workaround, or should I just adapt the macro to group consecutive equations into a `gather*` environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello.
\begin{equation*}
  AAAAAA
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
  BBBBBB
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
  CCCCCC
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
  DDDDDD
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Dario Do you mean leaving a blank line? [These answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77849/5699) seem to indicate that it would start the equations at the beginning of a paragraph, which is bad practice. Also, I'd prefer having the first space smaller, rather than have the others larger. Thanks for the idea, though!

Comment: Duperon. Yes this is what I mean. I just posted the MWE. I know it is not really great solution, but it seems to work.

Comment: Never leave a blank line before a displayed equation, or use two consecutive equations. Use an environment for a multiline display such as `align` or `multline` from `amsmath`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The larger space is `\belowdisplayskip` which is used for the first equation. You could locally set it to `\belowdisplayshortskip`. But some multiline display environment is probably better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello.%
\begingroup\belowdisplayskip=\belowdisplayshortskip
\begin{equation*}
  AAAAAA
\end{equation*}\endgroup
\begin{equation*}
  BBBBBB
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
  CCCCCC
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
  DDDDDD
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not “probably”: ***certainly***.

Comment: @egreg: I didn't check what the "AlignBox" in the question is meant to do, so I don't know the context of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not a nice solution, but it might work (just leave space between \end{} and \begin{}:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

Hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello.
\begin{equation*}
  AAAAAA
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  BBBBBB
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  CCCCCC
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  DDDDDD
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get:
[image]

Comment: No! _never_ leave a blank line before a displayed equation, it produces a spurious empty paragraph that looks like vertical space but is not lost at a page break.

Comment: Which solution then? I also tried using \vspace{} but it does not work.

Comment: I just saw your post. You are right. align should solve. Thanks

Comment: any multiline display environment such as `multline` or `align` from amsmath, or even the standard (but deprecated)  `eqnarray` would be better than this.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- you forgot the "obvious" one: `gather`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I know nothing about `amsmath` :-)