# Page layout design in KOMA script

Tags: margins, koma-script, paper-size

This is follow up of the previous question, [Document class for designing a book](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135046/document-class-for-designing-a-book).

Majority of respondents suggested that I design the the page layout using the class I was using for writing the text, in my case `scrbook`.

I have, of course studied the KOMA script manual and I find page layout settings pretty cumbersome.  The page is divided into *n* columns and *n* rows, of which outer two, inner one, bottom two and top one are margins.  On the other hand, I have the following instructions from the book designer:

```
page dimensions: 210 x 245 mm2
inner margin: 25 mm
outer margin: 10 mm
upper margin: 10 mm
bottom margin: 25 mm
text block width: 120 mm
```

My calculation from data above:

```
marginal notes width: 55 mm
```

I also attach the sample of the required layout, created in non-LaTeX program.

Please, advice me how to do this layout in scrbook class.  In this moment, I am interested in **page layout only**, as I have solved some of other design problems myself or with other people's help already.  Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using only `KOMA-Script`, the ratio between top and bottom margin will always be 1:2. Therefore, an additional package (e.g., [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry)) is needed for your desired layout. Note that you have to split your calculated "marginal notes width" into `marginparsep` and `marginparwidth` and to add both parameters to `outer`. See section 3 of the `geometry` manual for details and additional modifications (e.g., regarding headers/footers).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[
  paperwidth=210mm,
  paperheight=245mm,
  top=10mm,
  bottom=25mm,
  inner=10mm,
  outer=80mm,
  marginparsep=7mm,
  marginparwidth=48mm,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

Some text.\marginpar{\lipsum[1]}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```