# Looking for names of some length elements in KOMA script book

Tags: spacing, koma-script

After printing my thesis I realised that the spacing in the bottom and top of the document seem overly unbalanced (not an issue on pdf, but looks a bit odd in print, see figure in the bottom of the post), as shown by the red arrows in the picture below:

[image: example page]

Would anyone know what the names of these lengths are, and how to change them? I would like to move the main body of the text down around 4mm, and the number line as well.

I'm using a tweaked template based on KOMA scrbook, and I'm not loading the geometry package (except for showing the frames in the figure below with `\package[pass,showframe]{geometry}`).

Illustration printed version:
[image]

Comment: They're respectively `\headsep` and `\footskip`.

Comment: Did you saw question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139523/page-layout-design-in-koma-script ?

Comment: @Bernard \headsep seems to only affect the space above the header, not below it. And Mensch, no, I hadn't. Thanks for pointing out. So it seems I'll have to pull in geometry to get this fixed =/

Comment: Strange… That's the official name in basic LaTeX, but I don't very well `koma-script` and it has its own way the manage the page layout. The only mentioning of `\headsep`  that I found in the documentation was in the explanations about the `headsep` key, p. 404.

Comment: The fact that the bottom margin is twice as large as the top margin is by design; see chapter 2 of the manual. If you don't want this (and lose some of the features of KOMA Script), you can override it, e.g. with `geometry`. If you just want smaller margins, there are several possibilities to do that, depending on the details of what you want to achieve. Those are described in section 2.6 of the manual.

Comment: @schtandard, I'm fine with bottom being 2x top. I would just like to shift the whole main body some mm downwards. See edit, I'll add a photo of the printed result to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: @dangom But if you move it down, the ratio won't be 1:2 anymore, will it?

Comment: Indeed, of course. I wrote without thinking. Then perhaps what I want indeed is to simply move the whole thing 5mm downwards and break the 2x.